# Calculated value from a variable conditioned by a third variable in R

Tags: r

I´m working in R with a dataframe that includes 
`Patient_ID, date, ulcer_area(cm2), initial measure(yes/no)`.
Each patient has one or more measures of area (`ulcer_area`) in different dates
I´m trying to create for EACH patient a new variable called `area_dif` that is a proportion of de current measure and the initial measure

```
area_dif = by Patien_ID (ulcer_area/(ulcer_area WHERE initial measure=yes))
```

[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvgD2.png)

Comment: sample data, use `head()` or `dput()`

Answer (score 0):

i would use mapply

```
df = data.frame(Patien_ID = rep(1:4,3), ulcer_area = rnorm(12,5), 
                initial = rep(c("Yes","No", "No"),4))
str(df)
'data.frame':   12 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Patien_ID : int  1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 ...
 $ ulcer_area: num  4.48 5.27 5.38 4.63 4.45 ...
 $ initial   : Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Yes": 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 ...

df$area_diff <- mapply(function(i, area) {
  area/df$ulcer_area[df$initial == 'Yes' & df$Patien_ID == i]
  },
  i = df$Patien_ID, area = df$ulcer_area)

str(df)
'data.frame':   12 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Patien_ID : int  1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 ...
 $ ulcer_area: num  4.48 5.27 5.38 4.63 4.45 ...
 $ initial   : Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Yes": 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 ...
 $ area_diff : num  1 1.246 0.933 1 0.992 ...
```